Question about running a query from a TEMP table
Ok so im following a coursera course, and im running a SQL query that goes like this:
WITH  
 longest_used_bike AS (
  SELECT bike_id,
  SUM (duration_minutes) AS trip_duration
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips` 
  GROUP BY bike_id
  ORDER BY trip_duration DESC
  LIMIT 1 )
SELECT 
trips.start_station_id, ---- this line
COUNT (*) AS trip_ct
FROM 
longest_used_bike AS longest
INNER JOIN
 `bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips` AS trips
ON longest.bike_id = trips.bike_id
GROUP BY 
trips.start_station_id --- and this line
ORDER BY
trip_ct DESC
LIMIT 1


So the instructor is telling me to add "trips." before start_station_id but if i run the query without the "trips." line, i get the same result, any ideas why?
Also, it the asks me to run the query using OUTER JOIN but i get the same result, am i doing something wrong?
The database im using is the austin_bikeshare database in the public datas from bigquery, in case this matters

Regarding your first question on table prefixes:
The prefix trips. is useful as it explicitly indicates that your asking for a column (e.g. start_station_id) that belongs to the trips table. This is important when joining tables as it guards againts column name collisions.
Say longest and trips had any columns with the same name, e.g. bike_id,
SELECT
...
bike_id --- this would be ambiguos

SELECT
...
trips.bike_id --- this would be precise

As for your second question on JOINS
INNER and OUTER JOINS are different. INNER JOIN will only join rows that satisfy the ON clause. While OUTER JOIN will join any row regardless, and fill the missing values with NULL.
Say you had a row in longest whit a bike_id of 69, but in the trips table you don't have any row where bike_id = 69. In that case an INNER JOIN would ommit that row where an OUTER_JOIN would inclued it, with the data pulled from trips being filled with NULL values for that particular row.

@jarlh corrected, thanks

I am not 100% sure of how to answer your question as it is very hard to read. You should use a code block to maintain formatting for your code.
It sounds like you are struggling with understanding JOIN statements
Inner Join is going to join everything together that has a match: If you have a table that has "Product, CustomerId" and another table that has "CustomerId, email", you can JOIN those two tables on CustomerId; any rows that don't match will be omitted.
An OUTER JOIN will join everything together regardless, and fill nans in cells that don't match. It is also called a FULL OUTER JOIN.
I hope this is helpful in some way. JOINS are not the easiest thing to grasp at first, but you will get them eventually if you don't give up.

Don't forget LEFT [OUTER] JOIN and RIGHT [OUTER] JOIN. And nan is not the same as NULL.


So the instructor is telling me to add "trips." before start_station_id

It's a good habit to use table aliases to qualify column names, just in case both tables in the join include a column of the same name. You want to be specific about which table the column belongs to.
It may be unnecessary if only one table has a column by that name, or if they are bound to be the same value because it's the column you joined on (using =). But it's still a good habit to use qualified column names.

[if he] asks me to run the query using OUTER JOIN but i get the same result, am i doing something wrong?

No, an OUTER JOIN might give the same result as an INNER JOIN.
The result of a LEFT OUTER JOIN or RIGHT OUTER JOIN is a superset of the result of an INNER JOIN. But not necessarily a greater set.
If every row in one table has at least one matching row in the other table, then the two results are the same.
